# How to use decorators on object properties

Tags: angular

In the folloowing code I assign template element reference to `container` property on `MyComponent` class.

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('container') container;
  log(){
    console.log(this.container);
  }
}
```

How can I create `container` property on an object(the code below gives me an error)

```
class MyComponent {
  myObject = {
     @ViewChild('container') container;
  }
  log(){
    console.log(this.myObject.container);
  }
}
```

> Error: Propery assignment expected

Answer (score 3):

That line where you try to set up an object to equal the view container looks wonky.

Objects are created with key value pairs. But you are only providing a value.

Try this (I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but I guess if you're going to, you'd have to do something like this):

```
@ViewChild('container') myContainer;
myObject = {
     container : this.myContainer
}
```

Comment: Also in TS I'm not sure you'd need "this" if you use it immediately after the Viewchild annotation in the same function. I think you do (or that it wouldn't make a diff if you do or don't). Just keep that in mind if there's an issue.